# What is the alternative for table valued parameters in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I use table value parameter to send multiple rows of data to stored procedure in SQL Server and now since I am migrating to MySQL I want to know if their is an alternative to table valued parameter in MySQL.

Comment: Temporary table. Or serialized value (JSON, CSV, etc.) parsed in SP.

Comment: I want to pass the datatable from .net core web application to mysql stored procedure. In case of MSSqlServer we can pass table using table value parameter, so is their any similar solution in case of MySQL?

Comment: *is their any similar solution in case of MySQL?* No.